# jQuery / JS wait until image width adjusted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, load

I am having an issue with timing during the loading functions of my page. The issue that I need to get the width of an image after it has been

(1) Loaded

(2) 100% Width adjusted by CSS

The image width is set to 100% and adjusts about 300ms after the my AJAX POST is returned but I don't want to use a timeout at the load time may differ.

```
    parsed_return.forEach(function(entry) {
        entry.pages.forEach(function(page) {
            $('<div style="margin-bottom: 50px;">' + 
                '<div class="col-xs-1"></div>' + 
                '<div class="col-xs-10 page" id="' + page.id + '" style="padding: 0px;">' + 
                    '<img class="image" src="' + base_url + page.page_uri + '&dpi=150">' +
                '</div>' + 
                '<div class="col-xs-1"></div>' + 
            '</div>').data( 'page_id', page.id ).addClass( 'row' ).appendTo( '#page-view' );
            page_list.push(page.id);

            console.log($("#" + page.id + " img").width()); // Outputs 1279px (Natural)
        });
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log($("#page-view .page img").first().width()); // Outputs 1279px (Natural)
    },100);

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log($("#page-view .page img").first().width()); // Outputs 1267px (adjusted to 100% based on window size)
    },300);
```

I need to get the width of the image AFTER it has been adjust to 100% of the parent element (based off window size) and not run the next AJAX POST until then. Is there anyway for me to do this properly?

Thank you for looking!

Comment: Why don't you just get `#page-view .page` width???

Comment: What do you need it for? You could use an onload handler on the image

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for looking at this. #page-view .page returns the same values as img, unfortunately. I need the fully loaded/adjusted width as the next AJAX POST inserts images based on the width of the .page img

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realy recommend you using the [jquery.waitForImage](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) it does all the loading images for you, and after the loading you can play as you want with them.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately, when this event i hit the image is fully loaded but the CSS not applied yet

Comment: Check waitForImage, i'm nearly sur the CSS is loaded but verify ;)

EDIT:
"You may also set the CSS properties that possibly contain image references yourself. Just assign an array of properties to the plugin."

if you can access the css properties that means it's loaded :)

Comment: You're right, there is a property called waitForAll: true that can be set to force CSS to load first

Comment: Thank you so much @James Pratt-Delzenne

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#page-view .page img").first().width() == $("#page-view .page img").first().parent().width())
```

You could make a function that checks using above logic when the Image matches the parent width

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of code you can include in your css file to make adjustments to your image *before* media queries are executed:

```
body::before {
opacity:0.3;
background: url(/images/DNA.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
content: '';
z-index: -1;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position:absolute; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
}
```